# Treat div like a frame without glass using css and html

Tags: html, css

I am facing problem with overlapping div.

Please refer site my site : http://ayurved-infertility.in/index.html

As you can see in the site, top menu and left menu is inside div which is in absolute position and moving with the screen. And content is just behind the absolute div. Also I given background as transparent. so, we can see the behind text easily.

Now, my problem is if I put any hyperlink to the text that is just behind the absolute div, no-one can be able to click on the link because absolute div is overlapping.

So, how can I overcome from this problem ? If it is not possible then please suggest me a better way so, that my website look and functionality doesn't change and I can be able to click on hyperlink in the text.

Comment: Can you add a screencap, your relevant HTML & CSS, to your post for some clarification? From what it seems like, you need to set `z-index` of those elements. That will determine what element is on top of the other. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: I tried to remove and reset the z-index but by doing same main banner, side menu and top menu does not shown

Comment: Also you can try to do same using browser tools like firebug etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you could remove the height:500px of the element shown in the screenshot. Now you can click part of the text (green area).

[image]

After that you can either remove the left nav and be done with it.
Or place it outside of the table element and give it a fixed position. This is the quickest and easiest solution I can come up with.
In general you shouldn't be using this table method of positioning stuff on a website at all.

Comment: Thanks flink for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your floating/absolute divs should only be as wide as your left menu item

The DIV surrounding your DL (the menu) should be

```
width:140px;
position:absolute;
```